# Finding Frequency of signal with time and amplitude data using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals, fft

I have a data that has two columns time and corresponding amplitude of signal. I need to compute the frequency of the signal. How can do this. I read about scipy and numpy fft. But I really do not understand how to use them in my case.

[Lift Coefficient vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKbsc.png)

I need to Calculate the frequency for the signal that is after time say 4s. which seems periodic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get frequency axis from an fft function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730753/how-to-get-frequency-axis-from-an-fft-function)

Comment: Thank you Michael Szczesny. It helped.